# Testing thread sensitive execution of tasks

Tags: c#, multithreading, unit-testing

I have a function that is supposed to initiate a task composed of three executions chained together, with the first delegate executing on a worker thread with the subsequent two delegates executed on the main thread. It looks something like this:

```
public delegate object RunAsyncWorkerDelegate();
public delegate object RunAsyncMainDelegate(object arg);
public void RunAsync(RunAsyncWorkerDelegate workerFunction, RunAsyncMainDelegate mainFunction1, Action<object> mainFunction2)
{
   Task.Factory.StartNew<object>(x => { return workerFunction(); })
      .ContinueWith<object>(t => { return mainFunction1(t.Result) }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext())
      .ContinueWith(t => { return mainFunction2(t.Result); }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

This code works fine in production, but I would like to be able to verify that delegates are being executed on the correct thread in test. Unfortunatly, it seems like the tasks are not being
synchronized in the same manner as when executed in the main application. Ideally I would be able to do something like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestRunAsync()
{
    var mainthreadId = Thread.ManagedThreadId;
    var mainFunction1Thread = 0;
    var mainFunction2Thread = 0;

    Action mainFunction1 = x => mainFunction1Thread = Thread.ManagedThreadId;
    Action mainFunction2 = x => mainFunction2Thread = Thread.ManagedThreadId;

    RunAsync(x => {}, mainFunction1, mainFunction2);

    // wait for runAsync to finish

    Assert.AreEqual(mainThreadId, mainFunction1Thread);
    Assert.AreEqual(mainThreadId, mainFunction2Thread);
}
```

Trying this out shows me that the different delegates are actually being run on completely different threads, despite the `SynchronizationContext` being set.

Is there a better way to test this behavior in test?

Comment: It seems to me that you would have to actually create a `SynchronizationContext` for the current thread, as your unit-test environment likely doesn't have one. Whether it's worth the trouble depends on what you think the likelihood of the `RunAsync()` method being implemented incorrectly. It would also be helpful if you could explain why you aren't just using `await Task.Run(workerFunction); mainFunction1(); mainFunction2();` if you want the continuations in the current context.

Comment: I simplified the example a bit too much it seems. The mainFunction delegates depend on the return value of the asyncFunction. I'll update the question to reflect this.

Comment: I tried creating a `SynchronizationContext` with the new keyword, yet it did not seem to do much in the unit tests. Are you talking about creating a less trivial version which overrides the base class?

Comment: Thanks for the update. I still don't see why you can't use `await` in the `RunAsync()` method though: `object result = await Task.Run(workerFunction); mainFunction2(mainFunction1(result));`. Granted, that doesn't really address your main question about the `SynchronizationContext` (the answer to which is basically just "it doesn't exist"), but a better answer could be provided if we could understand the desire to text the continuations specifically in a sync context.

Comment: _"Are you talking about creating a less trivial version which overrides the base class"_ -- yes, you would have to implement a full-blown context that knows how to marshal delegate invocations back on to some specific thread.

Comment: Reason I'm not using await is simply because I'm stuck on C# 4.0 for the foreseeable future, I should have mentioned that, sorry. Thanks for the help regarding the SynchronizationContext, you've saved me a lot of work.